# Defintion of Linear Dependence/Independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Have been learning about linear dependence for the past week or so and I'm trying to get the concept down to a definition which can be easily understood.

If we have the set $s$:

$s = \{\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\b_1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}a_2\\b_2\end{bmatrix}\}$

We know that $s$ is linearly dependent if and only if:

$a_1(c_1) + a_2(c_2) = 0$

$b_1(c_1) + b_2(c_2) = 0$

... where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not both equal to $0$.

Based on this fact, are the below definitions that I have perscribed for linear dependence/independence correct?

**Linear Dependence**:

If a set is linearly dependent, then this means that a vector in the set can be represented by some linear combination of the other vector(s) in the set.

**Linear Independence**:

If a set is linearly independent, then this means that any arbitrary vector in $\mathbb R^{n}$ can be represented by some linear combination of the vectors in the set.

Comment: 1) right, 2) wrong.

Comment: What you are stating as the definition of **Linear Independence** would rather be the definition for **Generator set**

Comment: The first is right or wrong, depending on whether "a vector in the set..." means _some_ vector in the set or _every_ vector in the  set. Should at least be rephrased for clarity: "A set is independent if there exists a vector in the set which is a linear combination of the other vectors in he set".

Comment: You recieved 3 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

> Linear Dependence:
>
> If a set is linearly dependent, then this means that a vector in the
>   set can be represented by some linear combination of the other
>   vector(s) in the set.

Correct.

> Linear Independence:
>
> If a set is linearly independent, then this means that any arbitrary
>   vector in Rn can be represented by some linear combination of the
>   vectors in the set.

Incorrect. The set $$A=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$ is a linearly independent set, however, the vector $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ *cannot* be writen as a linear combination of vectors in $A$.

---

The concepts that are closely connected to linear independence, and also deal with what vectors can be written as what kind of linear combination, are the concepts of a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) and the concepts of a [span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span).

The topic is a little too broad to cover in detail on this site, but the general idea is this:

- A linear span of a set is the set of all linear combinations we can make from the set
- A set is linearly independent if it is not linearly dependent
- A set $S$ is a basis for vector space $V$ if the span of $S$ is $V$ and if $S$ is linearly independent.

Interesting things that follow from the definitions above include, but are not limited to:

- If $B$ is a basis for $V$, then every element $v\in V$ has only *one* way in which it can be written as a linear combination of elements from $V$.
- Each linearly independent set is a basis of the space that it spans
- All bases of a vector space have equal size

Comment: Okay, allow me to adjust the second defintion:

If a set is linearly independent, then this means that any arbitrary vector in **$R^n$** can be represented by some linear combination of the vectors in the set, providing that there are at least $n$ vectors in the set. Is this accurate?

Comment: @RyanWalter Yes, if a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is linearly independent, and it has $n$ elements, then its span is $\mathbb R^n$. But just to be clear: this is not the definition of what "linearly independent" means. I expanded my answer a bit, so I hope it is clearer. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: @RyanWalter I would instead suggest the following modification for your second proposition (it’s not a _definition_ of anything, per se): If a set of vectors is linearly independent, then every vector in their span has a **unique** representation as a linear combination of those vectors. In other words, a linearly-independent set of vectors forms a basis for their span.

Answer (score 0):

The last one is false and the others are right. Even a single non-zero vector in $\mathbb  R^{n}$ is linearly independent and you cannot write any vector as a linear combination of this vector. What is true is if you have $n$ linearly independent vectors $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ in $\mathbb  R^{n}$ then any vector can be written as a linear combination of these vectors.

Comment: Okay, my second definition is incorrect. But would I be correct in saying that any arbitrary vector in $\mathbb  R^{n}$ can be represented by some linear combination of the vectors in the set - providing that the set contains at least $n$ vectors?

Comment: Yes, if your linear independent set has $n$ vectors then  you can express any vector as  a linear combination of those. BTW you said at least $n$ but you can never more than $n$ independent vectors in $\mathbb R^{n}$

Comment: To be honest, at this current stage, I am not familiar with the concept of 'linearly independent' _vectors_. The definition I am trying to articulate relates to linearly independent _sets_ _of_ _vectors_. As I said, I haven't yet covered this topic thoroughly, I am just trying to develop a base level understanding of what can/can't be achieved with linearly independent sets of vectors. So all I am saying is that if there are $n$ (or more) vectors in a linearly independent set, then any arbitrary vector in $\mathbb R^{n}$ can be represented by some linear combination of the vectors in this set.

Answer (score 0):

Your extrapolation on linear independence cannot be right. Because if you consider $n$ linearly independent vectors and take one apart, the remaining $n-1$ ones cannot represent it, though they are linearly independent.

Even simpler: a singleton set is perforce linearly independent, but cannot generate the whole of $\mathbb R^n$.

---

Vectors are linearly independent iff the only linear combination that yields the zero vector is the trivial combination (all zero coefficients). In other words, vectors are independent if they are not… dependent.